# Vue-js Deep Watching

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I'm trying to watch an array using deep watch and update changes of the array to the local storage. When certain changes are done, the values in the local storage do not change but vue app developer tool shows that array values have been changed. What is the issue? Thanks in advance!

```
watch :{
  todos:{
    handler : function (){
      localStorage.todos = JSON.stringify(this.todos);  
    }
  },
  deep : true,
},
```

Comment: add `deep: true` like `handler:function){....},deep:true`

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim it was already there. Still not working

Comment: Your `deep: true` is not part of the object for the `todos` watcher. You instead have defined it as a separate watcher for something called `deep`. Move the `deep` property so that it is a property of the `todos` object.

Comment: @Bert yeah that was the problem. Thnak you